# SignalStrength values: what's the difference between cmda and evdo?

Tags: android

On a Verizon phone, a Motorola Droid X2, if I get the signal strength with a SignalStrength object and look at its values, both the cdma and evdo values appear valid.

If I print out a signalStrength.toString():

```
09-09 11:48:00.678: INFO/ConnectionStatusAndroid::onSignalStrengthsChanged(4773): *** Signal Strength:SignalStrength: 99 -1 -87 -70 -63 -1 5 cdma 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

If the phone gives out apparently valid values for both cdma and evdo, then what's the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EV-DO is a CDMA-based 3g standard, the other is one of the CMDA-based 2g standards.

Comment: so, ignoring wifi, if I wanted to give the user the signal strength of the "best" connection available, it would be EV-DO?

Comment: That's depending on what you mean by best, in the US EV-DO is almost exclusively used for data but other places it may be used for voice.  If best voice quality is what you'd like then use the 2g value for US users.